# Why am I getting request context as ApiGatewayV2 on making a websocket request (using lambda_runtime in rust)?

Tags: rust, aws-lambda, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to test the `$connect` route on my lambda function written in rust locally. Here is the code in `main.rs`:

```
use std::env;

use lambda_http::{run, service_fn, tracing, Body, Error, Request, RequestExt, Response, request::RequestContext};
use aws_sdk_dynamodb::{Client, types::AttributeValue};
use aws_config::{load_defaults, BehaviorVersion};

/// This is the main body for the function.
/// Write your code inside it.
/// There are some code example in the following URLs:
/// - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime/tree/main/examples
async fn function_handler(event: Request) -> Result<Response<Body>, Error> {
    // Extract some useful information from the request

    let config = load_defaults(BehaviorVersion::latest()).await;
    let client = Client::new(&config);

    if let RequestContext::WebSocket(request_context) = event.request_context(){
        let route = request_context.route_key;
        let connection_id = request_context.connection_id;

        match route {
            Some(route) => {
                if route == "$default" {
                    todo!()
                } else if route == "$connect" {
                    if let Some(conn_id) = connection_id{
                        handle_connect(client, &conn_id).await?;
                        return Ok(Response::new(Body::Text("Connected".to_string())))
                    } else {
                        return Err("Connection ID not found".to_string().into());
                    }
                } else {
                    todo!()
                }
            },

            None => todo!()
        }

    } else {
        println!("request type: {:?}", event.request_context());
        return Err("Incorrect request type".to_string().into())
    }

    todo!();
}

async fn handle_connect(client: Client, connection_id: &str) -> Result<(), Error>{
    let table = env::var("CONN_TABLE")?;
    let pkey = env::var("CONN_PKEY")?;

    client.put_item()
        .table_name(table)
        .item(pkey, AttributeValue::S(connection_id.to_string()))
        .send().await?;

    return Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    tracing::init_default_subscriber();

    run(service_fn(function_handler)).await
}
```

On testing this lambda function with `cargo lambda watch | grep "request type:` and making a request using `websocat ws://localhost:9000`, the request context is being shown as ApiGatewayV2httpRequestContext as opposed to WebSocket causing an internal server error to be returned.

How do I trigger the local lambda function so that the api gateway event payload forwarded to the function has the request context WebSocket? Is there a more fundamental gap in my knowledge which I am not able to see here?